# Was bedeutet eigentlich „freue mich“ am Ende einer E-Mail?

Tags: letter

Am Ende einiger Briefen steht neben einem Abschiedssatz (z.B. liebe Grüße, MfG, bis bald, und so weiter und so fort) manchmals der kleine Ausdruck *freue mich!*

- Was bedeutet der?
- Es ist einfach ein netter Zusatz zu dem Abschiedssatz, der ohne weiteren Zwecken   zu ignorieren ist oder muss man was antworten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja! Man muß mit "Ich freue mich auch!" antworten. :) 
Spaß beiseite!

Dieser Zusatz wird vor allem in E-Mails auftauchen, in denen irgendetwas für die Zukunft ausgemacht wurde, wie ein Treffen, Besuch oder ähnliches. Der Kommunikationspartner bekräftigt dann diese Vereinbarung und betont, daß er sich auf das Ereignis freut.

Beispiel:

```
A: Hast du Lust, mal mit mir ins Kino zu gehen?
B: Gute Idee! Morgen käme der 2. Teil vom "Kleinen Hobbit" im Capitol.
A: Klasse, den wollte ich schon lange sehen. Also morgen 19 Uhr am Capitol?
B: Abgemacht! ... freue mich ...
```

Comment: Oder in einer Bewerbung: "Ich freue mich von ihnen zu hören." Manchmal auch ungünstig im Konjunktiv formuliert: "Ich würde mich freuen von ihnen zu hören."

Answer (score 2):

"Freue mich" am Ende von einem Brief heißt wörtlich `I'm looking forward to it`. Ob du etwas darauf antwortest, hängt von dir ab, ist aber kein Muss.

Man schreibt "freue mich", oder "ich freue mich schon darauf" oft in Situationen wie im Beispiel von Ingo: man hat gerade mit jemandem diskutiert und typischerweise ein Treffen vereinbart. Im letzten Satz, nachdem der Plan schon steht, schreibt man oft die oben genannte Floskel. Wenn man nett ist, kann man darauf "Ich freue mich auch", oder einfach "Ich auch" antworten, muss aber nicht.